# How to load an existing ipython notebook?

Tags: python, ipython

I'm missing something really obvious here but I want to load an existing .ipynb file in my own ipython session. I've tried the following:

```
$ ipython dream.ipynb 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/me/develop/deepdream/dream.ipynb in <module>()
     33     {
     34      "cell_type": "code",
---> 35      "collapsed": false,
     36      "input": [
     37       "# imports and basic notebook setup\n",

NameError: name 'false' is not defined
```

(Google's deepdream notebook) but the json syntax isn't good? I am using the ipython from Anaconda 2.3.0, python 3.4.0 and ipython qtconsole 3.2.0.

Comment: 2024 update: This happens for me if I try to use `ipython` with Python's `multiprocessing` module. Jupyter notebook and Visual Studio code are fine. More here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77453594/315168

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You must [start `ipython notebook`](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/notebook/notebook.html#starting-the-notebook-server), otherwise `ipython` tries to execute `dream.ipynb` as though it were a file containing Python code:

```
ipython notebook dream.ipynb
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try to launch an ipython notebook server via `ipython notebook`, i.e. specifically this command and not the name of the notebook, and to simply load the specific notebook from your webbrowser.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use `jupyter notebook dream.ipynb`.

The `ipython notebook` command will be deprecated in the future.